# Querying the current user's identity using WindowsIdentity?

Tags: c#, single-sign-on, wif

I'm using WindowsIdentity to get the current user's ID to do SSO.  For the most part, I'm getting exactly what I want, but for some users I'm getting odd results.  Example code:

```
IIdentity WinId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
WindowsIdentity wi = (WindowsIdentity)WinId;
String idName = wi.Name.Replace(@"TESTHQ\", "");
```

Sometimes I get `duy@test.org` and I'm then able to sign in.  Other times I get jone@test.org/broadcast@test.org.

Is there a place where I can see the current identity using Windows 7?  Like in Control Panel or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Then you can change your code to split the values on `/`

try

```
WindowsIdentity MyIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
```

Comment: I don't understand why it's getting "jone@test.org/broadcast@test.org" Is there a way I can see where it's getting this information?

What will WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent do?